# How can I extract numbers between slashes in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a strings with this pattern,

```
ver1.1/hello/12345/bar -> extract 12345
world/098767123/foo   -> extract 098767123
ver1.2344/foo/78687115/ -> extract 78687115
```

I used `/\d+/g` or `/\d+/`, but didn't have luck that always `ver` numbers come too. How can I extract numbers which does not have any char and between slashes?

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group to capture only the numbers between slashes: `\/(\d+)\/`

```js
console.log("ver1.1/hello/12345/bar".match(/\/(\d+)\//))
```

Comment: it also extracts slush as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group for this, e.g.:

```
var regex = /\/(\d+)\//;
var string = "ver1.2344/foo/78687115/";
var match = string.match(regex);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

You can also use `/(?:\/|^)(\d+)(?:\/|$)/` for numbers that happen at the beginning or end of the string. This just has two non-capturing groups that say "match / or the beginning/end"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a map to the output of the match to strip out the slashes.
The use of the global flag `g` also prevented duplicate results.

```js
const regEx = /(?:\/)(\d+)(?:\/)/g;
const source = "ver1.1/hello/12345/bar";
const arrResults = Array.from(source.matchAll(regEx), m => m[1]);
console.log(arrResults)
```